# show alert view after certain score

Tags: ios, xcode4, uialertview, xcode4.3, alert

I'm creating a app on Xcode and i would like a alert view to show when they have click a button 100 times but for some reason when i click the button 100 times nothing happens i will show you all the code i have in the app at the moment and what i have done in the xib and whats connected to what hope you guys can help.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int counter;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *count;
}

-(IBAction)plus;
-(IBAction)minus;
-(IBAction)zero;

@end
```

implementation

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void) buttonAction {
    counter++;
    if(counter == 100)
        [self showAlert];
}


- (void) showAlert {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                          initWithTitle:@"Tile"
                          message:@"This is the message" 
                          delegate:nil 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

}

-(IBAction)plus {
    counter=counter + 1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

-(IBAction)minus {
    counter=counter - 1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

-(IBAction)zero {
    counter=0;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    counter=0;
    count.text = @"0";
        [super viewDidLoad];

}




- (void)viewDidUnload {


     [super viewDidUnload];
    }





- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


@end
```

thats all the code i have and the problem I'm getting is the counter works fine its just when i reach 100 nothing happens heres the images

[image]

[image]
and no alert 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a "buttonAction" function, I would just put the if statement inside your plus function. Something along the lines of this:

```
-(IBAction)plus {
    counter=counter + 1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
    if(counter == 100)
        [self showAlert];
}
```

It eliminates the need for that extra function, which would increase counter by too much if called anyway. (both plus and buttonAction tell counter to increase by 1, meaning every time plus is called counter increases by 2)

Comment: With this method I can't get the case where i'm on 101 and I press minus button

Comment: That is true. I hadn't realized you would want that as an option. In that case I would suggest either adding the `if(counter == 100){[self showAlert];}` to the end of the minus function. I believe this would probably be the easiest way to add the functionality you want. If you wanted to expand it to quite a few different buttons and methods I would suggest creating a function to check if it's 100, but for just two buttons a whole new method seems like overkill.

Comment: @ChanceR. hi there again I'm trying to add a button but its not going very well the point will say "rate this app" can you help buddy ?

Comment: so here are the steps I'd take to creating a button

Comment: 1.add button to view in interface builder, change the text to "rate this app"
2.instantiate it in viewcontroller @interface `IBOutlet UIButton *mybutton;`
3.create a property for it after the @interface `@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *mybutton;`
4.create a method that handles the button being pressed `-(void)buttonPressed;`
5.in the .m file, specifiy exactly what you want the button to do, in this case, it would probably go to the app store. I can't help you with that, but google has answers.
5.link the method in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call your "buttonAction" method. Try with this:

```
-(IBAction)plus {
    counter=counter + 1;
    [self buttonAction];
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

-(IBAction)minus {
    counter=counter - 1;
    [self buttonAction];
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}
```

Comment: yes thank you that work but for some reason it now counts up in two?

Comment: it will count two because you increment the counter both in Plus method as well as Button Action method :)